# Parse relational query on multiple geopoint

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using **Parse.com** as a backend to my app project. I have two classes `Deal` and `Outlets`. They are linked to each other via an array. `Deal` and `Outlets` have a one to many relationship as every deal can have multiple outlets. Hence,the geopoint information is kept in each outlet record.

I want to query the deal that is nearest to me within 5km. Is there a way for me to include/join the geopoint before calling the query? So far, the "includeKey" functions only does makes the result include the "outlets". But I need to include/join it **before** calling the geo query.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much.

Comment: you can user PFQuery's where constraint like  [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint]; and Pass the PFGeoPoint to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your Geo points are stored in your `Outlet` class, you do not want to run your Geo query on the `Deal` object but on the `Outlet` object. If we assume that an `Outlet` is offering a `Deal`, then any `Outlet` record can simply point to a `Deal` it is offering. Now simply perform a Geo query to find the nearest `Outlet` to you and then you easily get the associated `Deal` via the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lucas & Nazemi. I considered doing that before, however that would give me a duplicate of the same deal. For the same deal i would just want to see the nearest outlet as the subsequent outlets with the same deal is not as important. Thanks.